# How do I transfer data between android apps?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need to write a program (the first application) in which I need to enter text, click on a button and the data will be sent to the second application. In the second application, the data is encrypted and immediately returned to the first application as if the result of the function. The encryption function should be in the second application.
Roughly speaking, I want to make a "library" (or a server that will process requests) from an android application, to which you can send a request (string) and receive a response(string).

I think I can use Service. But I do not know how to launch it from the first application. How to establish a communication channel between applications. How to stop the service after that.

Comment: Why are you adding complexity and reducing security by using two apps? In terms of using a service, the use of bound services is covered by [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services).

Comment: @CommonsWare, This is my task, to use an unstable native library by any means, which may after a while call the abort function, which causes the application to crash. Perhaps you know how to prevent the native library from closing the application, and help me with the answer, I would be very glad.

Comment: That sort of isolation does not require two apps. Using two processes may be reasonable, with the service hosting the library operating in a separate process than the main app. See `android:process` on the `<service>` manifest element.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Sorry, I forgot to say that the native library should also not have access to native libraries and other data of the first application. Do you still know how to solve this?

Comment: Use [`android:isolatedProcess="true"`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element#isolated) on `<service>`.

Comment: @CommonsWare, also, the native library should access some other native libraries from the apk file. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, sure, as there would only be one APK file in what I am suggesting, and so everything would be in that APK file. You are certainly welcome to use remote bound services between two apps -- personally, I would go to great lengths to avoid this.